# Vim - how to store and execute commonly used commands?

Tags: text, editor, vim

If I wanted to process a batch of text files with the same set of commands for example:

> :set tw=50
> gggqG

Can I save the above and run it with a shortcut command?

Comment: I don't use ViM (Emacs... ;-)) but the feature you want must be called "macro" as everywhere, you should google for that.

Comment: You are looking for "vim macro".

Comment: Here it is : http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following in .vimrc will define a new command `Wrap` that does what you want.

```
command! Wrap :set tw=50 | :normal gggqG
```

Call it with `:Wrap`

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use it only once, use a macro as specified in some of the other answers. If you want to do it more often, you can include the following line in your [`.vimrc`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vimrc) file:

```
:map \r :set tw=50<CR>gggqG
```

This will map `\r` to cause your two lines to be executed whenever you press `\r`. Of course you can also choose a different shortcut, like `<C-R>` (Ctrl+R) or `<F12>` or something.

Comment: Can I map it to a typed command rather than a keyboard shortcut (like  executing a script)? I can imagine I'll run out of keys otherwise!

Comment: Yes, you can even map it to `hellomynameisjon` if you like :).

Comment: So that would be ":map \hellomynameisjon :set tw=50<CR>gggqG"? and I just hit ESC and then type it in?

Comment: No, the backslash is included in the keystroke. If you do it like that, you'd have to type `\hellomynameisjon`, with the backslash. Other than that, you are correct.

Comment: look at rson's solution to use it with a colon.

Answer (score 6):

As a very quick start, put this in your .vimrc:

```
" define the function
" '!' means override function if already defined
" always use uppercase names for your functions
function! DoSomething()
    :set tw=50
    gggqG 
endfunction

" map a keystroke (e.g. F12) in normal mode to call your function
nmap <F12> :call DoSomething()<CR>
```

note: the formatted code above looks rather horrible, but lines starting with " are comments.

Answer (score 2):

Other than macros, you can use `argdo`. This command will perform the same operation on all open files. Here is how you format all open files using [`:argdo`](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/editing.html#:argdo) and [`:normal`](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/various.html#:normal):

```
shell> vim *.txt

:argdo exe "normal gggqG"|up
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you go for writing a thousands-lines `.vimrc` (which is a good thing, but you can postpone it for a while), I think you might want to look at the plain recording, in particular  you may consider using the `q`*x* (where *x* is any key) for recording, `q` to finish recording and `@`*x* to execute recorded macro.

Comment: I will only run the macro once per file.  Is there any way to save the recording?

Comment: To tell you the truth, I have no idea ;-) I think not. But the recording persists across all files as long as you don't exit vim. Try `:help repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the important word is **macro**

But it seems like a 'command' such as :set tw=50 would be better included in the `.vimrc` file so vim uses it every time you start it up.